# Components with default property sets

Tags: javascript, attributes, reactjs, web-component

I'm looking for a way to set the default properties of a react component with one property. Rather then being repetitive every time I utilize a function with the same attributes. I'd like a way to reuse that component with those attributes without having to make it into it's own component.

Here's an example, even though there's only one property in each set. Imagine I have a couple of different presets each having 10 props / attributes each, it's way easier to call just one attribute and have all of them be filled in for you.

```
var List = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    var propSets = {
      "default":{
        "icon": "fa fa-wifi"
      },
      "fruits":{
        "icon": "fa fa-apple"
      },
      "vegetables":{
        "icon": "fa fa-tree"

      }
    }
    //setPropsViaProp
    if(typeof this.props.set === "undefined") return propSets["default"];
    return propSets[this.props.set];
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="list">
        <i class="{ this.props.icon }"></i>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

<List set="fruits">
<List set="vegetables">
```

This is throwing

> Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

I'm guessing props isn't defined yet within `getDefaultProps()`

Comment: The set is more like a computed property. You can't have it in the `state` but you can always make a function call to compute that in the render() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too late to modify the props of a component by the time you know what the `set` property will be.

You could instead use a mixin that installs a method of getting these properties:

```
var PropSetsMixin = {
    getProp: function(name) {
        // Simplified implementation for the answer, use better one in production
        return this.propSets[this.props.set][name];
    }
};


var List = React.createClass({
    mixins: [PropSetsMixin],

    propSets: {
        "default":{
            "icon": "fa fa-wifi"
        },
        "fruits":{
            "icon": "fa fa-apple"
        },
        "vegetables":{
            "icon": "fa fa-tree"
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="list">
                <i className={this.getProp("icon")}></i>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Or if you don't like function call:

```
var PropSetsMixin = {
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(props) {
        this._applyPropSets(props);
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        this._applyPropSets(this.props);
    },

    _applyPropSets: function(props) {
        var set = props.set || "default";
        this.propSet = this.propSets[set];
    }
};


var List = React.createClass({
    mixins: [PropSetsMixin],

    propSets: {
        "default":{
            "icon": "fa fa-wifi"
        },
        "fruits":{
            "icon": "fa fa-apple"
        },
        "vegetables":{
            "icon": "fa fa-tree"
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="list">
                <i className={this.propSet.icon}></i>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

getDefaultProps is only called once, so that won't work.  What you really want to do is to calculate the props when you need them.

```
var PropSetMixin = function(sets){
  return {
    getProps: function(){
        var set = this.props.set ? sets[this.props.set] : sets.default;
        return Object.assign({}, set, this.props);
    }
  }
}

var List = React.createClass({
  mixins: [PropSetMixin({
      "default":{
        "icon": "fa fa-wifi"
      },
      "fruits":{
        "icon": "fa fa-apple"
      },
      "vegetables":{
        "icon": "fa fa-tree"

      }
  })]
  render: function() {
    var props = this.getProps();

    return (
      <div className="list">
        <i class="{ props.icon }"></i>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

When you have some time later you can optimize this by caching the result in componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps, without changing the components using the mixin.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: check that variable in the if itself

```
if(this.props && typeof this.props.set === "undefined")
```

This way it'll check if there is a variable called this.props before trying to access it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops) you can't rely on `this.props` inside of `getDefaultProps`.  Might want do your calculation in `getInitialState` and store the result in some component level property.